# How to create pyspark dataframes from pandas dataframes with pandas 2.0.0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I normally use `spark.createDataFrame()` which used to throw me deprecated warnings about iteritems() call in earlier version of Pandas. With pandas 2.0.0 it doesn't work at all, resulting in an error below:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-2209449931455530>:64
     61 df_train_test_p.loc[df_train_test_p.is_train=='N','preds']=preds_test
     63 # save the original table and predictions into spark dataframe
---> 64 df_test = spark.createDataFrame(df_train_test_p.loc[df_train_test_p.is_train=='N'])
     65 df_results = df_results.union(df_test)
     67 # saving all relevant data

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py:48, in _wrap_function.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46 start = time.perf_counter()
     47 try:
---> 48     res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49     logger.log_success(
     50         module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature
     51     )
     52     return res

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:1211, in SparkSession.createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
   1207     data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)
   1209 if has_pandas and isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
   1210     # Create a DataFrame from pandas DataFrame.
-> 1211     return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
   1212         data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema
   1213     )
   1214 return self._create_dataframe(
   1215     data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   1216 )

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:478, in SparkConversionMixin.createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    476             warn(msg)
    477             raise
--> 478 converted_data = self._convert_from_pandas(data, schema, timezone)
    479 return self._create_dataframe(converted_data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:516, in SparkConversionMixin._convert_from_pandas(self, pdf, schema, timezone)
    514 else:
    515     should_localize = not is_timestamp_ntz_preferred()
--> 516     for column, series in pdf.iteritems():
    517         s = series
    518         if should_localize and is_datetime64tz_dtype(s.dtype) and s.dt.tz is not None:

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-fefe10af-04b7-4277-b395-2f16b77bd90b/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5981, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5974 if (
   5975     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5976     and name not in self._metadata
   5977     and name not in self._accessors
   5978     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5979 ):
   5980     return self[name]
-> 5981 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

How can I solve this? I use Spark 3.3.2. I did find seemingly updated code with problematic call replaced here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py but not sure which version it is and whether it is available.

EDIT: sample code which reproduces the problem below:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# create a sample pandas dataframe
data = {'name': ['John', 'Mike', 'Sara', 'Adam'], 'age': [25, 30, 18, 40]}
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert pandas dataframe to PySpark dataframe
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pandasToSpark').getOrCreate()
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas)

# show the PySpark dataframe
df_spark.show()
```

Comment: Please add your use case in detail. If possible your sample input and expected output.

Comment: sample code added

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It appears there is a package conflict with pyspark and the 2.0.0 release of pandas for now (which was released in PyPi April 3 2023 as the default). Hopefully pyspark folks put a fix soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a broken dependency.  The [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-42593) was recently merged.  It will be released in `pyspark==3.4`.

Unfortunately, only `pyspark==3.3.2` is [available](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark/#history) in pypi at the moment .  But since `pandas==2.0.0` was just released in pypi today (as of April 3, 2023), the current pyspark appears to be temporarily broken.

The only way to make this work is to pin to the older pandas version as suggested, until the next pyspark release.   Alternatively, you could attempt to pull the new pyspark from the [release candidates](https://github.com/apache/spark/tags).

Answer (score 0):

A viable approach is to directly convert the Pandas dataframe to the Parquet format, and then read the Parquet file using PySpark.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# create a sample pandas dataframe
data = {'name': ['John', 'Mike', 'Sara', 'Adam'], 'age': [25, 30, 18, 40]}
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame(data)

parquet_file = 'temp_data.parquet'
df_pandas.to_parquet(parquet_file)

# convert pandas dataframe to PySpark dataframe
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pandasToSpark').getOrCreate()
df_spark = spark.read.parquet(parquet_file)

# show the PySpark dataframe
df_spark.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering is because the `iteritems()` method has been removed in `Pandas 2.0`. Instead, you can use `items()` method which does the same thing.

To solve this issue, you need to update the code where you are using `iteritems()` method. One way to do this is to replace `iteritems()` with `items()`. You can update the following line of code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Emily"],
    "Age": [25, 32, 18, 47, 21],
    "City": ["New York", "San Francisco", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Boston"],
}

pdf = pd.DataFrame(data)

for column, series in pdf.items():
    print(column, series)
```

**Output**

```
Name 0      Alice
1        Bob
2    Charlie
3      David
4      Emily
Name: Name, dtype: object
Age 0    25
1    32
2    18
3    47
4    21
Name: Age, dtype: int64
City 0         New York
1    San Francisco
2          Chicago
3      Los Angeles
4           Boston
Name: City, dtype: object
```

Alternatively, if you still need to use `iteritems()`, you can downgrade your Pandas version to one that still supports `iteritems()` method. You can do this by running:

```
!pip install pandas==1.2.5
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue, as iteritems() is called in spark. I know that I can solve this by downgrading pandas, but I am interested specifically in a solution with Pandas 2.0.0

Comment: You can call `items()` method in spark. This is available in `pyspark.pandas` dataframe method. See this official documentation [spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.html)

Comment: I am using spark.createDataFrame() method to create pyspark dataframe from pandas dataframe. This method uses the deprecated call to iteritems().